# GROUP BY members of a comma delimited list

Tags: sql, mysql

I have a table of data as follows:

```
t1
____________________________________________________
resources          | companyName | Response | Score 
David, Matt        |  companyA   |  YES     |   5
Matt               |  compqanyB  |  NO      |   8
Kyle, Kyle, David  |  companyC   |  YES     |   2
```

As you can see, `resources` is a comma delimited string. Also, not all members of `resources` have to be unique (See row 3).

I want to `GROUP BY` each `DISTINCT` member available in any list. All of the other columns will be aggregated.

Intended Result:

```
query
______________________________________________________________________________
resources     |  companyName        |    Response         | Score
David         | *agregated result*  | *agregated result*  | *agregated result*  
Matt          | *agregated result*  | *agregated result*  | *agregated result*  
Kyle          | *agregated result*  | *agregated result*  | *agregated result*
```

**EDIT:**

Another Possibility:

```
query
____________________________________________________
resources          | companyName | Response | Score 
David              |  companyA   |  YES     |   5
Matt               |  companyA   |  YES     |   5
Matt               |  compqanyB  |  NO      |   8
Kyle               |  companyC   |  YES     |   2
David              |  companyC   |  YES     |   2
```

Comment: I don't think you can do this with a pure SQL, but it shouldn't be too difficult in any programming language (php, java, etc.)

Comment: I'm using this for reporting services, so I am trying to go direct to the database. I'd rather not use a middle man if I don't have to. But if it's not possible, then I guess I'd have to.

Comment: you can do it in SQL but you'll have to use a cursor.  which, is more like a SQL imitation of real programming langauges, so i'd rather not go there.

Comment: The end result is to have each resource get credited with the score from a ticket they were associated with. I edited my OP, is this new direction possible? With another row for each resource?

Comment: I guess that's really just the same question with no `GROUP BY`

Comment: Which RDBMS? This is tagged with both mysql and tsql, which seems odd.  Also, do you have a table of just the resources?

Comment: It's actually MS SQL, but the question is a SQL-logic question more than db-specific. And yes I do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me assume that you have a table of resources with the individual names.  In that case, you can do what you want with the following query:

```
select r.name, <other aggregated results>
from t1 join
     Resources r
     on concat(', ', t1.resources, ', ') like concat(', %', r.name, ', %')
group by r.name
```

If you don't have a table of resources, you probably should.  Storing such things in comma delimited lists is in general a bad idea.  It is a particularly bad idea if the data is not normalized, and misspellings arise.

Comment: Unfortunately, I was stuck with this database. I did not create it. And I believe I do have a table for resource names. Let me try this out.